# Can't use .replaceWith() second time. How can I replace it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

guys! I need to replace .replaceWith() with something similar because .replaceWith() can't be called twice on the same element. I tried to use .html() and .empty().append(), but none of them working.

This is the block of code:

```
      context["comments"] = comments;
      var ratingTemplate = Handlebars.templates["comment_rating"];
      var template = Handlebars.templates["show_comments"];
      Handlebars.registerPartial("comment_rating", ratingTemplate);
      Handlebars.registerPartial("show_comments", template);
      Handlebars.registerHelper(handlebarsHelpers);
      $("#load-comment-section").hide();
      $("#comment-section")
        .replaceWith(template(context))
        .promise()
        .done(on_comment_section_load());
```

What would be the best approach? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. What do you REALLY need to do? Show and Hide stuff?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't be called twice"? What happens in this case?

Comment: @mplungjan not show/hide stuff, just replacing that element, #comment-section, with the handlebars template

Comment: @NicoHaase after calling .replaceWith() on an element, the element is actually replaced, so the second time there is not element to call .replaceWith() on

Comment: So, if there is no element to call `replaceWith`  on, what should that code do instead? If it is meant to replace something that isn't there, it's pretty obvious that it cannot do anything

Comment: @NicoHaase yep, I know that, but the first use of the code was to call replaceWith only once in a page session. so that's why I am asking this